# Crystal Reports app crashes when printing on Windows XP (WPF)

Tags: wpf, printing, crystal-reports

This issue happens on version **13.0.4** ([downloaded from here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)) **(32bit)** using WPF.

I'm using the WPF Crystal Report Viewer. If I click the print button, the application simply crashes showing the window telling you that you could send this information to microsoft.

To avoid any other chance of bug, I developed a sample app with a Report within showing just a label. Then the issue occurs on a machine with Windows XP service pack 3

**EDIT : I traced the following stacktrace**

```
at System.Windows.Size..ctor(Double, Double)
at SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ReportPaginator.GetPage(Int32)
at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.Toolbox.GetPage(System.Windows.Documents.DocumentPaginator, Int32)
at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.NgcDocumentPaginatorSerializer.SerializeObject(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.NgcSerializationManager.SaveAsXaml(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter.SaveAsXaml(System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter.Write(System.Windows.Documents.DocumentPaginator)
at System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.PrintDocument(System.Windows.Documents.DocumentPaginator, System.String)
at SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.PrintControl.Print()
at SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ReportAlbum.PrintReport()
at SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.CrystalReportsViewer.PrintReport_Executed(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(System.Windows.Input.CommandBindingCollection, System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.Input.ICommand, Boolean)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.Input.ICommand, Boolean)
at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.IInputElement, Boolean)
at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteCore(System.Object, System.Windows.IInputElement, Boolean)
at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(System.Windows.Input.ICommandSource, Boolean)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()

at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at TestCrystalReports.App.Main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION**
I had no choice, I put a button over the Crystal Report Viewer's button and I called the ReportDocument's PrintToPrinter method

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the printer association in the page setup of the report?

Comment: Yes I did. the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The crash is related to the PrintDialog and the enumeration of existing printers.

After many hours of debugging and googling i found a working solution:
Install (or reinstall) .NET framework 3.5 SP1.
This will install 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer' Printer driver.

Really don't know why, but after installation the issue magically disappeared.